# adding a linear layout defined in xml at the footer of listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-linearlayout

i am trying to add a linear layout defined in xml at the footer of a listview. i tried the below code

```
listview.addFooter(findViewById(R.id.my_linearlayout))
```

but it is throwing an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
```

if i just remove the addFooter code the acitvity runs smoothly.can one please suggest what is issue or if it is the right way to add the linearlayout at the footer of listview dynamically.
thanks in advance.

Comment: first inflate the linearlayout in View. then add it to footerview. Let me know if you still have any problem.

Comment: Do you want to scroll the layout with your listview or do you want it to be the seprate view???

Answer (score 2):

View footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_linearlayout, null);
listview.addFooterView(footerView);

You should add my_linearlayout to your /res/layout/ folder.

Comment: that worked perfectly... Thanks! Others are also correct but this seems straight forward !

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in way

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.list_footer_layout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

here list_footer_layout name of xml file into in layout folder.

Layout for footer like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="7dip"
    android:paddingBottom="7dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/list_footer_layout" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView 
        android:text="@string/footer_text_1" 
        android:id="@+id/footer_1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textSize="14dip" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity class could be

```
public class MyListActivty extends ListActivity {
    private Context context = null;
    private ListView list = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        //code to set adapter to populate list
        View footerView =  ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.list_footer_layout, null, false);
        list.addFooterView(footerView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, listview, false);
listview.addFooter(linearLayout);
```